# How can I return a value from a JDialog box to the parent JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, return-value, jdialog

I have created a modal JDialog box with a custom drawing on it and a JButton.  When I click the JButton, the JDialog box should close and a value should be returned.

I have created a function in the parent JFrame called setModalPiece, which receives a value and sets it to a local JFrame variable.

The problem is that this function is not visible from the JDialog box (even though the JDialog box has a reference to the parent JFrame).

Two questions:
1) Is there a better way to return a value from a JDialog box to its parent JFrame?

2) Why can't the reference to the JFrame passed to the JDialog be used to access my JFrame function setModalPiece?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should do the opposite by adding a custom method `getValue()` to your custom `JDialog`.

In this way you can ask the value of the dialog from the `JFrame` instead that setting it by invoking something on the `JFrame` itself.

If you take a look at Oracle tutorial about dialogs [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) it states

> If you're designing a custom dialog, you need to design your dialog's API so that you can query the dialog about what the user chose. For example, CustomDialog has a getValidatedText method that returns the text the user entered.

(you can find source of `CustomDialog` to see how they suppose that you will design your custom dialog)

Answer (score 120):

I generally do it like this:

```
Dialog dlg = new Dialog(this, ...);
Value result = dlg.showDialog();
```

The `Dialog.showDialog()` function looks like this:

```
ReturnValue showDialog() {
    setVisible(true);
    return result;
}
```

Since setting visibility to true on a JDialog is a modal operation, the OK button can set an instance variable (`result`) to the chosen result of the dialog (or `null` if canceled). After processing in the OK/Cancel button method, do this:

```
setVisible(false);
dispose();
```

to return control to the `showDialog()` function.

Comment: Thanks for this! I've been searching for the last hour on how to accomplish this, and this worked exactly as I wanted.

Comment: Small comment - if you use JDialog you have to declare it as modal, via the correct parameter in the constructor or via SetModal(true);

Comment: FYI, an update on @Oz Radiano's helpful comment:

setModal
This method is obsolete and is kept for backwards compatibility only. Use setModalityType() instead.

Comment: e.g., this.setModalityType(DEFAULT_MODALITY_TYPE);

Comment: To elaborate further on why this works, `setVisible(true)` from `java.awt.Dialog` does not return until the dialog is hidden by calling `setVisible(false)` or `dispose`. (information from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#setVisible(boolean))

I was a bit confused because I thought `showDialog` would simply make the dialog visible and immediately return whatever `result` is referencing to.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if I can explain my method in a cool way...
Let's say I need productPrice and amount from a JDialog whos going to get that info from user, I need to call that from the JFrame.

declare productPrice and ammount as public non-static global variables inside the JDialog.

```
public float productPrice;
public int amount;
```

* this goes inside the dialog's class global scope.

add these lines in the JDialog constructor to ensure modality

```
super((java.awt.Frame) null, true);
setModalityType(java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
```

* this goes within the dialog's class constructor

let's say your JDialog's class name is 'MyJDialog' when calling do something like this

```
MyJDialog question = new MyJDialog();
MyJDialog.setVisible(true); 
// Application thread will stop here until MyJDialog calls dispose();
// this is an effect of modality
//
// When question calls for dispose(), it will leave the screen,
// but its global values will still be accessible.
float myTotalCostVar = question.productPrice * question.ammount;
// this is acceptable.
// You can also create public getter function inside the JDialog class,
// its safer and its a good practice.
```

* this goes in any function within your JFrame and will call JDialog to get infos.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass any value to JFrame to JDialog then create parametrized constructor of jdialog and in jframe whenever you want to call. 
e.g. The parametrized constructor like :

```
 public EditProduct(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal, int no) {
      //int no is number of product want to edit.
      //Now we can use this pid in JDialog and perform whatever you want.
}
```

When you want to pass values from JDialog to JFrame create a bean class with set and get method the the values using vector and get these values in jframe.
[More info](http://www.tutorialdata.com)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I usually do it. I wasn't sure, that's why I've created that post:

[Returning value from JDialog; dispose(), setVisible(false) - example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18330494/returning-value-from-jdialog-dispose-setvisiblefalse-example)

Answer (score 0):

Add an interface to your constructor?

```
public class UploadConfimation extends JDialog {

private final JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();


public interface GetDialogResponse{
    void GetResponse(boolean response);
}



/**
 * Create the dialog.
 */
public UploadConfimation(String title, String message, GetDialogResponse result) {
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    setTitle(title);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    contentPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    contentPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    getContentPane().add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    {
        JLabel lblMessage = new JLabel(message);
        contentPanel.add(lblMessage);
    }
    {
        JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
        buttonPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        getContentPane().add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        {
            JButton okButton = new JButton("YES");
            okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    result.GetResponse(true);
                    dispose();
                }
            });
            buttonPane.add(okButton);
            getRootPane().setDefaultButton(okButton);
        }
        {
            JButton cancelButton = new JButton("NO");
            cancelButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    result.GetResponse(false);
                    dispose();
                }
            });
            buttonPane.add(cancelButton);
        }
    }
}
```

}