# Get a value from JDialog to the parent JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I added a jDialog Swing Form to my project as in this image :

[image]

and now I want to get the value from that jtextField to the parent JFrame when I close this JDialog, I googled about it and I found this :

```
Object obj=sasirMdp.showDialog();
```

but the compiler tells me that there is no method named `showDialog` in my JDialog.

and when I added this method  to the JDialog class :

```
ReturnValue showDialog() {
    setVisible(true);
    return result;
}
```

the copmiler tells me if I want to create the class `ReturnValue`.

Please if some one knows how to get that value from the `JDialog`, I'll be thankful.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089311/how-can-i-return-a-value-from-a-jdialog-box-to-the-parent-jframe

Comment: @Heuster yes I read about that post, it doesn't helped me the accepted answer is to read the manual, and I couldn't get what I want when I read it

Comment: Ok, could you add some code of your JDialog and how you invoke it? Then it's easier to point out how to apply that answer to your project.

Answer (score 2):

I seems to me that you are mixing up JDialog and JOptionPane. You should read [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html). It is a great introduction to dialogs with swing.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this?

```
public class TestJDialog extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
private JLabel l;

public TestJDialog(String title)
{
    super(title);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
    JButton  b = new JButton("Input Dialog");
    b.addActionListener(this);
    this.add(b);

    l = new JLabel();
    this.add(l);

    setSize(300, 100);
    setVisible(true);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
{
    String s = evt.getActionCommand();
    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this,
                                               "Saisissez votre mot de passé:",
                                               s,
                                               JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    l.setText("Mot passé: " + input);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new TestJDialog("Example");
}
}
```