# Returning value from JDialog; dispose(), setVisible(false) - example

Tags: java, swing, dispose, jdialog

I know, that this question appears quite frequently in SO like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089311/how-can-i-return-a-value-from-a-jdialog-box-to-the-parent-jframe):
but I would like to present some very specific example... I'm simply not sure if I make things right.

I've got a JDialog in which I can type some values, select some checkboxes... whatever...
I've got also some Response object created in MyDialog which represents the MyDialog's "answer".

In JFrame which calls/creates JDialog:

```
MyDialog d = new MyDialog(this, ...);
d.showDialog();
// After MyDialog is closed (it's modal):
MyDialog.Response dialogResponse = d.getDialogResponse();
// Do something with response...
```

In Dialog (dialog can be closed by clicking "Save" button):

```
btnSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        dialogResponse = prepareResponse(); // prepares response on the basis of some data introduced by a user; dialogResponse is called from JFrame after Dialog is closed
        setVisible(false);
        dispose();  // <-- Important
    }
});
```

My question is:
This solution works, I mean, the line `MyDialog.Response dialogResponse = d.getDialogResponse();` returns proper values, but...
if I close the dialog using dispose(), all dialog's resources can be garbage collected (don't have to... hard to predict, am I right?). So is it correct to retrieve my dialog's response it that way... Maybe in this case I should write only  `setVisible(false);` without `dispose()`.

Comment: if you need your `JDialog` later don't dispose it and just use `setVisible(false)`, otherwise you can dispose it without any problem

Comment: Not sure I understand, hence the comment, but can't you dispose the Dialog from the Frame?

Comment: @npinti Yes, but I'm mainly curious if I can access my dialog's response after dispose() is invoked on Dialog

Comment: If I understood your question in the right sense, why not make a class called `DialogResponse` as you fill values in your dialog, make necessary changes with your `DialogResponse` class's object and simply `return` this object to the parent `JFrame`, that way you really doesn't have to worry about `JDialog` being dispose or not, and moreover, you can use the same class for further updation, if the same `JDialog` is used again to get response. Though use this if your `JDialog` has huge to share with your parent class.

Comment: could u please help me on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31652594/how-to-update-jtextfield-after-click-save-button/31652855#31652855 ? I already change the JFrame to JDialog. Now I have problem save the JDialog contents.. @guitar_freak

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quoted from the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose%28%29):

> The Window and its subcomponents can be made displayable again by rebuilding the native resources with a subsequent call to pack or show. **The states of the recreated Window and its subcomponents will be identical to the states of these objects at the point where the Window was disposed** (not accounting for additional modifications between those actions).

So, your Response will be kept. All `dispose()` does is releasing the native screen resources, other members aren't marked for garbage collection.

Also, if you want to be extra sure, you could just call `dispose()` right after you retrieved your response object.

Answer (score 3):

> if I close the dialog using dispose(), all dialog's resources can be
>   garbage collected (don't have to... hard to predict, am I right?). So
>   is it correct to retrieve my dialog's response it that way... Maybe in
>   this case I should write only setVisible(false); without dispose().

- not true that [something is GC'ed only non_important value for Graphics/2D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309407/remove-top-level-container-on-runtime)
- there isn't some reason to create this Object on runtime, [re_use this Object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18253888/714968)

Answer (score -1):

why you don't use class variables (private static or public static) and use a factory method

```
  //it can be an object too public static Object  getResponseValue()
  public static Integer  getResponseValue(){
    myclassContainer container = new myclassContainer(someparent,modal).setvisible(true)
     return      Myfieldvalue
    }

    private static int Myfielvalue;

}
```

Comment: ??? clearly i missed a part here ....come on class variables are good they are necesary thats why we have them, factory methods constants like jdialogs butons you should read more

Answer (score -1):

```
        dialog.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, tree_tmp);
        JButton confirm = new JButton("YES");
        confirm.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                confirm.setActionCommand("kkk");
                dialog.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        dialog.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH,confirm);
        dialog.setSize(400, 400);
        dialog.setVisible(true);

        System.out.println(confirm.getActionCommand());
```