# How to update JTextfield after click SAVE button

Tags: java, eclipse, jbutton, jtextfield

I have a main frame : JFrame>contentFrame>ScrollPane>BigPanel>panel_1T

```
private JPanel contentPane;
private JPanel BigPanel;
private JPanel panel_1T;
```

In panel_1T, I have put a FOOD button WITH its actionListener:

```
JButton button_19 = new JButton("FOOD");
button_19.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

            newFoodUI nf = new newFoodUI();//Open other class
            nf.setVisible(true);
            nf.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);      

                                                 }
                                               });
panel_1T.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2, 0, 0));
panel_1T.add(button_19);
```

When user click FOOD button, new JFrame in `newFoodUI` class will be shown.:
JFrame>contentPane>panel>tabbedPane>panel_3>panel_5

In panel_5, I put a JTextField:

```
public static JTextField textField_3;

textField_3 = new JTextField();
panel_5.add(textField_3, "9, 4, fill, default");
textField_3.setColumns(10);
```

User will write some text into `textField_3`. Then user click SAVE button in panel_3, it will perform this:

```
JButton button_4 = new JButton("SAVE");
button_4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                setContentPane(contentPane);
                panel_3.revalidate();
                panel_3.repaint();
                panel_3.updateUI();

                panel_5.revalidate();
                panel_5.repaint();
                panel_5.updateUI();


                contentPane.revalidate();
                contentPane.repaint();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Saved !");

        }
    });
    button_4.setBounds(873, 396, 75, 33);
    contentPane.add(button_4);
}
```

The result is, when I click SAVE button and close the Frame in newFoodUI, I will reopen back by click the FOOD button to check whether the text I wrote has been saved or not. But its not saving the text I wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to save the value from the textfeld `textField_3.getText()` and set this value manually to textfeld when showing `textField_3.setText(value)`. So you have to keep your value in your project or store persistent somewhere.

Comment: I got the solution in terms of coding at http://raiseyouup.blogspot.com/2015/07/how-to-save-jtextfieldinput-by-user-in.html

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things to fix here and I will not give you complete code but I will point out some errors. First let's consider your `button_19` listener

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

        newFoodUI nf = new newFoodUI();//Open other class
        nf.setVisible(true);
        nf.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);      

}
```

When this is performed, it creates a totally new object of `newFoodUI` and gives it no parameters. So how could this frame know about anything that happened before its creation if you give it nothing? Additionally, you explicitly say `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`, when you could use `HIDE_ON_CLOSE` if you wish to reuse it.

Then in your `JButton button_4 = new JButton("SAVE");` listener you want to save the data in the text field, but your implementation does nothing to the text field. You should, for example, get the text from `textField_3` and write it to a file or send back to the first `JFrame`.

[Then there is the issue of using multiple `JFrames` in the first place.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice)

Comment: Thanks for telling about the multiple JFrames and need to change JFrame to JDialog.. but I still use `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` because it still show the saved text..

Comment: @doraemon dispose is perfectly good. Hiding is a way to not having to create the object with `new` all the time.